# How do I have a user input a boolean phrase and then have my IDE output it in binary form?

Tags: java, input, binary, boolean, bluej

I want to have a user input something like: True, False, True, True, False

and that will output 01101

This is my code:

```
 public static void main()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the Binary phrase? (True/False)");
    String phrase = input.nextLine();



    if(false)
    {
        System.out.print("0");
    }
    else if (true)           
    {
        System.out.print("1");     
    }
}
```

but this only outputs a single value of 1, regardless of the input being true or false

I want my code to have the initial input of:

boolean [] binaryValues, Graphics g, int x, int y but I don't know how to use it to get my desired output

Update: My code can now print a 0 or 1 depending on the input but I still need help with converting True, False, True, True, False to 01101

Answer (score 0):

```
if(phrase.toLowerCase().equals("false"))
    {
        System.out.print("0");
    }
    else         
    {
        System.out.print("1");     
    }
```

You have to check for your input..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
if (scanner.nextBoolean() {
   // print something
}
else {
   // print something else.
}
```

Note : You will have to use `scanner.hasNextBoolean()` to check if a boolean value exists in the stream before actually reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare if you input is the same as the string representation of the boolean.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the Binary phrase? (True/False)");
    String phrase = input.nextLine();



    if(phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
    {
        System.out.print("0");
    }
    else if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))           
    {
        System.out.print("1");     
    }
```

In your code, you are checking `if(false)` which is always going to not be triggered, and then `else if(true)` which will always be triggered. That is why 1 always displays. You are passing direct boolean values into your if statements, not completing a check.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  for(String x : in.nextLine().split(",\\s?")){
     System.out.print(new Boolean(x).booleanValue() ? "1" : "0");
  }
```